# Foward slash (/) Python syntax

Tags: python, syntax

I found this code in [the fast.ai course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast.ai#Massive_Open_Online_Course):

```
path = untar_data(URLs.PETS)/'images'
```

It downloads a [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) file from an URL.

I have never seen this syntax before (a function call followed by / and string).

What is going on?

Comment: The "/" operator cannot deal with strings. It is clearly a syntax error and that line you mentioned never gets evaluated.

Comment: I runs just fine in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `pathlib.PurePath` overloads the slash operator to perform joins (somewhat controversially) https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators

Comment: The `untar_data` function might be returning an object that defines the `__truediv__` method which overwrites standard division behavior. The code is essentially equivalent to `untar_data(URLs.PETS).__truediv__('images')`